# How to format a title attribute with css (setting more width)?

Tags: html, css

I have written the following html code:

```
<img src="myImages/defaultImages/myPic.jpg" title="myFirstValue: 'DescriptionOfMyFirstValue', &#10;mySecondValue: 'DescriptionOfMySecondValue', &#10;myThirdValue: 'DescriptionOfMyThirdValue'" />
```

That creates a nice tooltip with some linebreaks, but my area, in which the tooltiptext is visible, is too small. How can i create a much bigger area for my tooltip?

Thanks !

Comment: specify the width of the area you want to enlarge

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is currently not possible to format a tooltip. An alternative solution is to use one of the many open source projects that allow for custom HTML based tooltips and then modify their content.

These are some common solutions.

- [jTip](http://www.codylindley.com/blogstuff/js/jtip/)
- [jQuery Tooltip](http://jquery.bassistance.de/tooltip/demo/)